# CSS - Unsure if this value is currently valid for overflow property

Tags: css, overflow

I was checking over some of the CSS for one of our sites when I came across:

```
overflow: no-display;
```

I had never heard of this so Googled and found [this](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/overflow) page, which seems to suggest it's valid. However, at the MDN site for overflow (click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)) there is no mention of `no-display`. There is also no sign of this value on the W3C doc [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow).

Is "no-display" a valid value for overflow, or perhaps a deprecated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `no-display` value for the overflow property seems to have never made it past the [W3C working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) stage. If you see it in legacy code, it may be because browsers at the time wanted to support the latest experimental features before they were recommended by W3C.

If you look [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) and scroll to CSS Basic Box Model Level 3 where the `no-display` value is mentioned within, you can see that the notes for the *working draft* mention "Dangerously outdated; see [CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/)'.

[CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) nor the upcoming [CSS2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/) mention the `no-display` value for the overflow property.

In a practical sense, you can consider the `no-display` value of the overflow property *obsolete*, as it doesn't even work in the major browsers (e.g., Firefox and Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

> overflow: no-display;

I have not seen this value "no-display"

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

This will give you all the information on the "overflow" property

Comment: But who's to say the webplatform.org reference (1st link above) is not correct, considering W3 Schools is widely snubbed on SO?

Comment: http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/overflow/   | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow    http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/position/overflow.htm    I do my homework from multiple sites.  These are just a few references.

Comment: Basically just wondering if anyone definitively knows the answer because the front end people at my company are pretty good...hard to believe they would make such a blatant error